# Python 3.5 UnicodeDecodeError for a file in utf-8 (language is 'ang', Old English)

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, nltk

this is my first time using StackOverflow to ask a question, but you've collectively saved so many of my projects over the years that I feel at home already.

I'm using Python3.5 and nltk to parse the Complete Corpus of Old English, which was published to me as 77 text files and an XML doc that designates the file sequence as contiguous segments of a TEI-formatted corpus. Here's the relevant part of the header from the XML doc showing that we are, in fact, working with TEI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader type="ISBD-ER">
    <fileDesc>
```

Right, so as a test, I'm just trying to use NLTK's MTECorpusReader to open the corpus and use the words() method to prove that I'm able to open it. I'm doing all of this from the interactive Python shell, just for ease of testing. Here's all I'm really doing:

```
# import the reader method    
import nltk.corpus.reader as reader

# open the sequence of files and the XML doc with the MTECorpusReader    
oecorpus = reader.mte.MTECorpusReader('/Users/me/Documents/0163','.*')

# print the first few words in the corpus to the interactive shell
oecorpus.words()
```

When I try that, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/util.py", line 765, in __repr__
    for elt in self:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 397, in iterate_from
    for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 291, in iterate_from
    tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/mte.py", line 25, in read_block
    return list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, XMLCorpusView.read_block(self, stream, tagspec, elt_handler)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/xmldocs.py", line 307, in read_block
    xml_fragment = self._read_xml_fragment(stream)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/xmldocs.py", line 252, in _read_xml_fragment
    xml_block = stream.read(self._BLOCK_SIZE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 1097, in read
    chars = self._read(size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 1367, in _read
    chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 1398, in _incr_decode
    return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 59: invalid start byte
```

So, as I'm a valiant StackOverflowsketeer, I've determined that either one or more files is corrupted or there's some character in the file(s) that contains a character that Python's utf-8 decoder doesn't know how to handle. I can be fairly certain of this file's integrity (take my word for it), so I'm pursuing

I tried the following to reformat the 77 text files with no apparent effect:

```
for file in loglist:
    bufferfile = open(file, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
    bufferfile.close()
loglist = [name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)]
```

So my questions are:

1) Does my approach so far make sense, or have I screwed something up in my troubleshooting so far?

2) Is it fair to conclude at this point that the issue must be with the XML doc, based on the fact that the UTF-8 error shows up very early (at hex position 59) and the fact that my utf-8 error replacement script made no difference to the problem? If I'm wrong to assume that, then how can I better isolate the issue?

3) If we can conclude that the issue is with the XML doc, what's the best way to clear it up? Is it feasible for me to try to find that hex byte and the ASCII it corresponds to and change the character?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: One thing to try: if you open the document in a text editor or web browser that auto-detects character encodings, what encoding does it think the document is in?

Comment: It indeeds look like the XML file is not a valid UTF-8 file. Just a guess at solving this: find the actual encoding of the file (that'll be the annoying part), read the file as plain text with that encoding, then save it as UTF-8 and you might end up with a valid UTF-8 encoded XML file. Provided there are no binary (CDATA) sections in the XML file.

Comment: Hey all--thanks for confirming my suspicions about the XML doc. So the header at the top of the XML doc specifies that its encoding is utf-8, and indeed I'm able to open it in Sublime Text with UTF-8 encoding. I'm wondering if my tools are actually working a bit too well here and converting encodings for me automatically...I'll play around with it a bit more, but so far my attempts to save the encoding as UTF-8 from various editors is making no difference.

Comment: @gatsbysghost I don't know if your dataset is (remotely) the same, but NLTK does include a [corpus reader](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/ycoe.html) for the Toronto/York [corpus](http://www.ota.ahds.ac.uk/) of OE. Maybe you can use that instead; little you can do if the encoding is off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conversion technique didn't work because you never read and wrote the file back out again.

`0x80` is not a valid byte in UTF-8 or any iso-8859-* character set. It is valid in Windows codepages, but only Unicode can support Old English characters, so you have some very broken data.

To convert UTF-8 with bad bytes do:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as input,
        open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output:

     output.write(input.read())
```

If you don't care about losing data, you may get away using the `encoding` argument on MTECorpusReader:

```
oecorpus = reader.mte.MTECorpusReader('/Users/me/Documents/0163','.*', encoding='cp1252')
```

which will make `0x80` a Euro (€) symbol.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I knew something wasn't right with the way I was trying to reformat the character sets in the files. Thank you so much for helping me to correct my Python ignorance--I'm still learning!

Comment: This is all correct, but since the corpus is pretty old, it's very likely using a base 8-it character set with custom extensions for the missing symbols (ð, þ etc.). It's probably in the documentation that came with the corpus, but if not, it should not by hard to figure out the meaning of each custom byte by examining the file, if you know even a little Old English. Why don't you try that, and come back with a question about how to convert a file from a custom 8-bit encoding to Unicode (it's pretty simple).

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is not supported in NLTK. At all. I suspect that if it's old English, it will need to make use of some strange letters.

There is, however, a solution that can minimize headaches. There's a library that's considerably more modern and powerful than NLTK, called `spacy`. [Here's a link.](http://spacy.io)

Spacy demands that *everything* be Unicode, while NLTK demands that *everything* not be. It's not worth the headache involved. Plus, NLTK's processor will *only* work on completely Unicode-free strings, which can give some messed up results.

Comment: How did you ascertain the character was `À`?

Comment: Read the error carefully. 
`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 59`
It's an invalid byte in utf-8. So it can't figure out what it is. But the closest neighbor is either a control character or that symbol.

Comment: In which character set is `À` the closest character to `0x80`?

Comment: I will *absolutely* check out spacy. Thank you so much for figuring that character out, as well! As @AlastairMcCormack points out, my conversion didn't do anything because I botched my for-loop for the file i/o, but honestly it would be easier to just use a library with native support.

Comment: @gatsbysghost the advice about `À` is a red herring - there is no codepage or character set where `À` is `0x80`. There's one where it's `0x8E` but that's not how character sets work. And computers certainly don't just choose a nearby mapping!

Comment: @gatsbysghost I've updated my answer to weed out wrong info. If either of our answers have been helpful, please consider upvoting and selecting an answer.

Comment: @Ares further, the `encoding` attribute on `MTECorpusReader` seems to indicate that NLTK can read XML documents encoded in any encoding, including UTF-8 (an encoding of Unicode), which is the default. http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html also mentions processing Unicode. As this is Python 3, Unicode is mostly abstracted away from the users, where `str` is the norm

Comment: Sure, but to do any kind of NLP or meaningful computations, the Unicode chars need to be dropped. For what he's doing, the fact that the `MTECorpusReader` is able to do that is irrelevant. It's frustratingly problematic to work with Unicode in NLTK and random errors **will** continue to pop up if you don't completely purge all Unicode characters immediately.

Comment: What makes you think the NLTK cannot handle Unicode? This is simply false. If you feel that this or some other specific module is particularly unstable, you can say so (or file a bug report).