# UnicodeDecodeError when reading text from corpus (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, python-unicode, corpus

I am trying to read text files contained in a corpus and place the contents of the files into a list. 
My code is as follows:

```
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(root, '.*\.txt')
files = corpus.fileids()

print (files)
dox = list()

for f in files:
    doc = corpus.raw(f)
    dox.append(doc)

print(dox)
```

I have encountered the following error repeatedly,

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position
>   257: invalid start byte

How do I prevent this error? Is there any code I can use to remove utf-8 coded characters from text?

Comment: Relevant, possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094812/understanding-unicode-in-python-and-unicodedecodeerror

Comment: you don't have to remove utf-8 coded characters you just have to decode it to utf-8. and encode it again.

Comment: @bhattravii , how do I do that? I have tried it and I get an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode

Comment: @AndreaPrakash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363747/python-3-5-unicodedecodeerror-for-a-file-in-utf-8-language-is-ang-old-englis this answer might help you and if not just let me know.

Comment: Yes, @bhattravii the solution provided there worked. Thank you so much for your help.